# why does google places return different results when changing sensor value?

Tags: google-places-api, google-places

I've read that the sensor parameter in places request doesn't affect results. However, if I make the same call once using sensor=true, and in the other one using sensor=false, results are different. Here is the call is use 
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/json?location=46.769967,23.589501&radius=1245&types=establishment&sensor=true&key=YourApiKey

Can anyone explain why does this happen?

Comment: What do the returned `json` objects look like? How different are they? **What** is different?

Comment: when using sensor=true results contain 2 parks. With sensor=false, no park is returned

Comment: I just tried it, and found no differences between the two calls. Perhaps you hit a momentary bug that's been fixed?

Comment: Yes, it seems it was a bug. Now I get the same results with both calls. But I'm still curious how this happened :)